# Are the tax rates same for income from salary, rental, and odd jobs?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, ontario

As per this [link](http://www.taxtips.ca/taxrates/on.htm), the tax rates in Ontario are divided into Other Income, Canadian Dividends, and Capital Gains.

Do all kinds of Income (rental, salary, odd jobs, etc.) come under Other Income? And all are taxed at the same rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for personal income. All personal income that is not from capital gains or eligible Canadian dividends is treated as *Other income* and subject to the same marginal tax rates.